how use fzf-lua to prompt with directory listing ; then file listing in selected directory
I would like to use fzf-lua to prompt for a specific directory listing and then prompt for files in the selected directory. I have looked at the fzf-lua github repo and the advanced options are really over my head at this point. I believe I have to use 'actions' to accomplish this, but I don't know where and how.  With the example below the idea is the function prompts with a listing of all the directories under ~/projects.   Then when a directory is selected, the action should spawn an new fzf-lua command to list the files in that directory.  When a file is selected it should be opened.   Thanks for any help!
function Projects()
  coroutine.wrap(function()
    local actions = {
      ["default"] = {
        require("fzf-lua").files { cwd = project },
      },
    }
    local project = require("fzf-lua").fzf_exec("ls", { prompt = "Projects> ", cwd = "~/projects" })
  end)()
end

